# Plotting a bar graph along a spline

Tags: seaborn

I'd like to plot a bar graph but in such a way that the bar graph isn't contained within a square/rectangle, but rather have the bottoms of the bars follow a spline. How can I get seaborn to output something like this? `seaborn.bargraph` doesn't have any parameters that would take a spline, which makes it really hard to combine data visualization and art.

Comment: Haven't tried but can you try to have an area plot that looks like a curve and color it the same as the background so that it will cover the bottom of the barplot?

Comment: You will need to use matplotlib and set a `clip_path`